# XBASE-Input -> com.linuxense.javadbf.DBFException: Failed to parse Number: multiple points

Tags: visual-foxpro, pentaho-data-integration, xbase

I have a problem with the "Extract from XBase File" ste in pentaho data integration
I can't extract file content and I have this error :

> 2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : Unable to read row : com.linuxense.javadbf.DBFException: Failed to parse Number: empty String
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : Erreur inattendue
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 - Unable to read row from XBase file
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 - Failed to parse Number: empty String
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 - 
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.xbaseinput.XBase.getRow(XBase.java:231)
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.xbaseinput.XBaseInput.processRow(XBaseInput.java:121)
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 - Caused by: com.linuxense.javadbf.DBFException: Failed to parse Number: empty String
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 -   at com.linuxense.javadbf.DBFReader.nextRecord(DBFReader.java:329)
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.xbaseinput.XBase.getRow(XBase.java:163)
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 -   ... 3 more
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 - Fin lecture enregistrements, fermeture fichier(s)...
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - Extraction depuis Fichier XBase.0 - Fin exécution étape (Entrées=0, Sorties=0, Lues=0, Ecrites=0, Maj=0, Erreurs=1)
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - C:\Users\NSE1\Desktop\EPP2017\Tables\articles_transformation.ktr : articles_transformation - Transformation détectée 
>   2017/03/10 10:01:14 - C:\Users\NSE1\Desktop\EPP2017\Tables\articles_transformation.ktr : articles_transformation - La transformation est en train d'arrêter l'exécution des autres étapes!

Can someone help me please?

Comment: "Failed to parse Number: empty String" you have an empty value and it can't be parsed

Comment: Yes @EgorZhuk in the .dbf file I have many empty colums .. but even if I fill in all columns I get the same error!

Comment: I shouldn't change the .dbf file content..Can I found a solution to extract the dbf data in this case?

Comment: I've checked it - works for an empty numbers. I've used the file from here https://www.drivehq.com/folder/p3922707/1271447624.aspx  Also there is a corresponding issue in a Penatho jira http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-496 Bu the way, what version are you using?

Comment: I use the last one : 7.0

Comment: I've also checked it with the file from the link .. it work also => The error is caused by the file .. How can I resolve this ?! :(  (I should read the file as it is)

Comment: First of all try to understand what goes wrong. Check your file with any other dbf viewing/editing software and find the difference